# Check if the channel is full discordJS

Tags: discord, discord.js

how do you check if the channel is full in discordJS v13?

ex. if the !join then if the channel is full return a message

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the channel object first. Then use [VoiceChannel.full()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=full) to check if a voice channel is full.